# Hadoop and Ambari alerts (Sandbox)

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, sandbox, ambari

I am trying to make a virtual environment with Oracle VM Virtualbox to use the Hadoop Environment... everything seems to work fine but then I find 26 alerts... The system does not allow me to fix the alerts... Somebody nows what is going on?

[image: Problem Ambari]

Comment: It seems multiple processes are in stopped state. Are you unable to start them from the Ambari itself?

Comment: It is just too slow when starting the processes. It took him 15 minutes just to start 1 proccess.

Comment: You have installed almost everything on a single host. The host is overloaded. So this slowness is expected, more so, some of the services might not even work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start everything and allow some times for alert states to reset.  Additionally, you have a bunch of services in maintenance mode which may have already thrown an alert before maintenance mode.   Last but not least, having all of services installed in same sandbox, I assume single node, can cause some of them to throw alerts and errors as the environment is not sufficient to operate everything at the same time.

Comment: I think your last sentence might be the answer... the question is how could I get more nodes?

Comment: Not sure that is possible for your "sandbox", but adding another node is easy otherwise.  Just delete anything you do not need to have for your testing purposes.  Try to get HDFS, Hadoop (yarn, mr), zookeeper, Ambari Metrics as a base cluster.  Then add the other stuff you need.   DO NOT ADD EVERYTHING.

Answer (score 0):

I could not make it work in windows. I installed it on a Ubuntu partition and worked fine. Thanks for your help.